# 3D look using :before selectors. Not selectable text

Tags: css, border, pseudo-element

Here you can see what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/smogg/QFa4J/2/embedded/result/
I was trying to achieve this look so hard, and right now this code may be really confusing. If you have some tips which may clarify that, please tell me. It is all made by trial and error.

Anyway, this looks good. The only problem is my text inside `.article` is not selectable. Borders inside `.article:before` cause this problem. How can I solve this? Or maybe I should take some different steps to achieve this look (right now, with my solution I have to define height of articles which is problematic).

@edit:
I forgot about this. I can't use `z-index` cause my `#main`has shadow on it (which is not included in jsFiddle to clarify code) and then shadow shows on top of border. If I use borders without `:before` then my `#main` gets wider, which is not what I want.

Comment: fyi - it looks like it's working in IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are cleaner and easier ways to do this. Enjoy!

http://www.css3d.net/ribbon-generator/

http://www.pvmgarage.com/2010/01/how-to-create-depth-and-nice-3d-ribbons-only-using-css3/

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/creating-nice-3d-ribbons-with-pure-css3/

Comment: Ohh, so its called ribbon ;) Thank you very much!